# Java LinkedBlockingQueue source code confusion

Tags: java, blockingqueue

I am reading Java `LinkedBlockingQueue` source code, and I have two questions about the [`put` operation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#LinkedBlockingQueue.put%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    // Note: convention in all put/take/etc is to preset local var
    // holding count negative to indicate failure unless set.
    int c = -1;
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>(e);
    final ReentrantLock putLock = this.putLock;
    final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
    putLock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        /*
         * Note that count is used in wait guard even though it is
         * not protected by lock. This works because count can
         * only decrease at this point (all other puts are shut
         * out by lock), and we (or some other waiting put) are
         * signalled if it ever changes from capacity. Similarly
         * for all other uses of count in other wait guards.
         */
        while (count.get() == capacity) {
            notFull.await();
        }
        enqueue(node);
        c = count.getAndIncrement();
        if (c + 1 < capacity)
            notFull.signal();
    } finally {
        putLock.unlock();
    }
    if (c == 0)
        signalNotEmpty();
}
```

I don't understand:

1. It checks `c + 1 < capacity`, when it emits `notFull.signal()`. Why not use `c < capacity`?
2. Why it emits `signalNotEmpty` when `c == 0` at the end of function?

Besides, I also don't understand why head/tail need to be `transient`?

Comment: Is Java 6 really the version you are  interested in?

Comment: @Tichodroma There are virtually no changes to this method in Java 7 or 8. I'll add the code for Java 8.

Comment: OP, I've added the relevant source code for Java 8. Can I change the link to the Java 8 version as well?

Answer (score 4):

The answers to your two questions:

1. Before the `c + 1 < capacity` check, there's a call to `c = count.getAndIncrement();`. Since the count is incremented *after* it's retrieved and assigned to `c`, there's a difference of **1** between `c` and the actual count, hence the `+ 1` in the check.
2. The not-empty signal only needs to be sent when the queue transitions from being empty to being not-empty. This is only the case when the first element is added to an empty (0 elements) queue. As to `c` at this point being **0** instead of **1**, refer to the answer to the first question.

About the `head` and `tail` being `transient`: they don't need to be persisted upon object serialization, because they're initialized through the default constructor upon object deserialization.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the trick for getAndIncrement(). The head/tail are pointing to node with null value in the default constructor. Does it mean that if we serialize/deserialize the blocking queue, we lose the content in the blocking queue?

Comment: The `head` is always an empty node in this implementation. You won't lose anything.